# EF Power Tools Beta 2 and Visual Studio 2012 Express

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I can't seem to get EF Power Tools to install with VS2012 Express for Web.  Is it only compatible with Standard or Ultimate Editions of VS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is not compatible with Express edition because Express editions don't allow installing plugins.